# Need help with understanding

Tags: meaning

Kindly explain what does "real community of people" mean here?
Did the author mean "real problems of community"?
Gabe is known as a guy who believes you will be successful if you focus on solving problems for a real community of people."
http://www.eater.com/2015/11/24/9788798/chefsteps-sous-vide-gabe-newell-immersion-circulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what does "real community of people" mean here?

The term *real* appears to be a reference to the sense of community spirit, and contrasts *real communities* with mere collections of people who happen to be given the label of being a community. For example, people who live in the same multi-storey building who don't even greet each other in passing may be termed a "community" as a technicality, but would not be called a *real* community.

In this context, a *real* community faces problems that its members care about. The quote then asserts Gabe's belief that when you solve the problem, you participate in something meaningful to the community. *Success* could refer either to that as an end in itself, or also to the rewards that go along with it. Applying the same 'solution' to an indifferent community may not be meaningful at all, resulting in no success in either sense.

Answer (score 1):

> *Did the author mean "real problems of community"?*

I believe you are correct in your understanding. In the given context, it does appear to refer to **real (or burning) problems**, as opposed to, say, **hypothetical (or simply less important) ones**. Here's the context:

> Every six months he'd say, **'What problems are you having, what are you
>   trying to solve?'** Gabe is known as a guy who believes you will be
>   successful if you focus on solving problems for a real community of
>   people."

Evidently Gabe's questions indicate that a business is successful if it pinpoints **a real problem** and then addresses it.

A little earlier, Gabe says: *...you have to have **a really good connection with the inside of someone's head** to be good at it.*

This again seems to indicate that the focus here is on understanding the customer, the **actual, real problem** they are facing.